# Вылетает QtCreator при попытке открыть существующий проект

Tags: qt

При любой попытке взаимодействия Проводника и Qt Creator последний вылетает. Сталкивался ли кто-то с таким? Как исправить?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Раньше Creator не дружил с русскими символами в пути, возможно проблема в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать новый проект с максимально простым путём (короткий, без пробелов и кириллицы), далее сохранить его и закрыть ide. Потом попробуйте открыть этот проект, если будет ошибка, то это уже интересно.